# Want to Trigger DataFlowpipeline with CloudFunctions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a scenario that we want to trigger a data-flow pipeline via cloud function, And in data Flow pipeline we have to transform some data and insert in big query

1. I had created our custom data_Flowpipeline and transformed the Data inserted in the big query (follow standard way of installing Apache beam and using Deployment command from cloud Shell) Pipeline ran successfully, log is showing in monitoring with DAG.
2. Now what I want do is to trigger the pipeline with cloud-function and for that I researched that
   (i)we can create custom flex template of pipeline
   (ii) stage it in google Bucket
   (iii)Call it with REST-API from cloud function

is the mentioned step in second step is recommended way of doing it or should I try another approach? I don't get any other way apart from classic templates

Comment: With dataflow, either you push your code, or you reuse a template. In your case, you Cloud Functions won't host the code, so the template is the correct solution for that.

Comment: okay great thanks guillaume